# Dividing long list of <li> tags into columns?

Tags: css

I've got a list of about 30 `<li>` in a `<ul>`. Is there any way, using CSS, to divide these into three columns of ten?

Comment: Is it possible to break it up into three <ul>'s?

Comment: Yeah,agree w/ Grant. Do it programatically.

Comment: Ugh, nothing worse than programmatically creating HTML in ASP.NET.

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, don't use ASP.NET, that's just masochistic. Use JavaScript.

Comment: The data that needs to get into those lists is in an XML file. How would I approach loading that XML file in JavaScript? Ajax and responseXML?

Comment: Yep.                   .

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In CSS3 this is [possible](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html).

```css
#columns {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="columns">
  <ul>
... lots of lis ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

The list items will spill over into the next column as they exceed the height of the container.

Perhaps for older browser you could use JavaScript, as this seems to be more aesthetic than a critical feature.

Comment: What browsers support CSS3? I'm afraid you may be too-cool-for-school. :(

Comment: "Currently supported by Firefox 1.5+ and Safari 3" and I would suppose Chrome and other Webkit derivatives. No IE :(

Comment: Some answers get better when they age :)

Comment: This is a little old, but still: column support is minimal. Check it out browser support information here: http://caniuse.com/multicolumn

Comment: for me adding the div before ul and applying column count to div didn't work, instead applying column count directly to ul worked.

Comment: This is now supported in all modern browsers. IE 10 and up also support it.

Answer (score 8):

I usually set the widths at 28% and float the to the left:

```
ul li {
   width: 28%;
   margin: .5em 2%;
   float:left;
}
```

The downside to this is that items fill like:

```
- - -
- - -
-
```

Not like:

```
- - -
- -
- -
```

If you want vertical filled columns, you need 3 <ul>s.

Comment: or just do `column-count:3; column-gap:10px;`

Comment: Yeah back in '09 css3 wasn't all it is today.

Answer (score 0):

The following is tailored to be mobile friendly.

```css
div.a {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1%;
  text-align: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
ul.a {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li.spacea {
  float: left;
  width: 2%;
}
li.thirda {
  color: #ff00ff;
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
}
li.thirdb {
  color: #ffff00;
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
}
li.thirdc {
  color: #00ffff;
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <ul class="a">
    <li class="thirda">
      The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    </li>
    <li class="spacea">
      &nbsp;
    </li>
    <li class="thirdb">
      The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    </li>
    <li class="spacea">
      &nbsp;
    </li>
    <li class="thirdc">
      The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```