# What is the best way divide content between n columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I have read this excellent [Multi-column list article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists), as well as [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486349/dividing-long-list-of-li-tags-into-columns).  I've come to the conclusion that there is no cross-browser way to turn a long unordered list into *n* columns of equal length.  So far, I have been reduced to multiple-ul solutions like this:

```
//Three columns.
string col1 = string.Empty;
string col2 = string.Empty;
string col3 = string.Empty;
int currItem = 0;
int collectionCount = myItemCollection.Count;

foreach item in myItemCollection {
  currItem++;
  if (currItem < collectionCount * .33)
  {
    col1 = col1 + item.someProperty
  } 
  else if (currItem < collectionCount * .67)  
  {
    col2 = col2 + item.someProperty
  } 
  else
  {
    col3 = col3 + item.someProperty
  }
}

string allColumns = @"<ul>" + col1 + "</ul><ul>"
                      col2 + "</ul><ul>" + col3 + "</ul>";

Response.Write(allColumns);
```

Is there a simpler way to separate my list into groups of three, or better yet, to simply write the appropriate closing/starting ul tags when an element is the last item in a "third"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I personally would choose to implement it.

```
const int numColumns = 3;
const int numColumns = 3;
var columnLength = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)myItemCollection.Count / 3);

for (int i = 0; i < myItemCollection.Count; i++)
{
    if (i % columnLength == 0)
    {
        if (i > 0)
            Response.Write("</ul>");
        Response.Write("<ul>");
    }
    Response.Write(myItemCollection[i].SomeProperty);
}

if (i % columnLength == 0)
    Response.Write("</ul>");
```

You avoid string concatenation altogether (there's really no need when you're just writing to a stream, and if you weren't you'd want to xse `StringBuilder`) as well as those nasty floating point operations which could potentially cause inaccuracies for long lists (at the very least they're unnecesary).

Anyway, hope that helps...

Comment: Excellent.  With some minor cleanup this code worked absolutely perfectly.  Exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: Glad it did the trick for you... (Also let me know if it contained any bugs so I can edit it, otherwise I will assume that you simply made small modifications for your own specific uses.)

Answer (score 1):

This is too late, but Response.Write will output in an unpredictable place, most likely ahead of all other output.

The "proper" code should be building controls on CreateChildren, Page_Load or any other place:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>() { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee" };
int colSize = (int)Math.Ceiling(items.Count / 3.0);

HtmlGenericControl ul = null;
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    if (i % colSize == 0)
    {
        ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(ul);
    }

    HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    li.InnerText = items[i];
    ul.Controls.Add(li);
}
```

This way you don't need to be concerned about rendering and tracking opening/closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an unordered list, you can just float the <li> left and give it a width of a little bit less than (100 / n)%