# CSS - break long list into columns by height

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm trying to create a multi-column list but the result I'm getting is not the desired.

In [this example](http://www.dimiourgiko-vildiridis.gr/sitemap.php?lang=en), I need to break the right list into a 2nd column at when the height reaches i.e. 400px and the same with the rest of the `<li>` elements (in the link above, I want to break the column into 2 after "BABY GIFTS" and put "MEN" in the second column.

I've tested many things such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509106/css-ways-to-break-list-into-columns-on-page) [Is there a way to break a list into columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509106/css-ways-to-break-list-into-columns-on-page) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486349/dividing-long-list-of-li-tags-into-columns) but it doesn't create the column where I want.

Here's the result I'm after [image] and here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HVZkG/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of how you want it to appear? Also provide JSFiddle code for the part of the code that you have done.

Comment: If you dont care about older browsers you could use columns:

info: http://quirksmode.org/css/columns/

Comment: Please see my question, I've added jsfiddle and a demonstration of the desired output.

Comment: Didi you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The solutions in both questions you've referenced that involve the columns property work as they should.  Your content can't split where you want it to because the 400px cutoff is too small.

http://jsfiddle.net/HVZkG/1/

```
#productsitemap {
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -moz-columns: 3;
    columns: 3;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: I see your point. I'll think it over and see about it. Thanks.

Comment: There *are* properties that allow you control breaks without controlling the height.  For instance `ul { break-inside: avoid; }` would force a break to happen before or after a list, but not inside.  Note that Webkit browsers use the older name of this property (`-webkit-column-break-inside`) and Firefox doesn't support it at all.  There's also `break-before` and `break-after` to explicitly force breaks.