# Ordered List that automatically separates into columns, based on parent div height

Tags: html, css, html-lists, multiple-columns

I have a div (for this example we'll call it #container) that has a height set to 100% of the page. In #container, I have an ordered list that will have 101 items. I am looking for a clean, efficient method of having the ordered list break into columns based on #container's height. As you can imagine, an ordered list of this size would expand vertically much larger than #containers height is. I want the OL to automatically break into columns so that #container doesn't have to expand.

Comment: can you use javascript?

Comment: check out this answer from an similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486349/dividing-long-list-of-li-tags-into-columns

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
#container {
width:100%; //or whatever width you have
height:100%;
}
ul {
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style:none;   // gets rid of typical behavior of ul
}
li {
position:relative;
width: 200px; // some specific width, play with this value.
height: 200px;
float:left;
}
```

I would recommend adjusting size of list items accordingly to available width of screen through @media directives and rather using percentage than fixed sizes.

BTW : i believe that you should also be using `#container {min-height:100%;}` because i dare say you dont always have space available in one screen.