# Displaying records in two columns

Tags: php, html, mysql

can someone tell me how to display all records generated from mysql database in two columns because the number of categories in my database are all displayed in one column and I would like to have them displayed in two columns, like this[image: books database]

Here is my php code;

**index.php**

```
<?php 

$dbh=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die ('Cannot connedt to the Database' .mysql_errno()); 
mysql_select_db("booksdb");


?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Select a Company</title>

</head>

<body>


<?php 

$res_query = mysql_query("SELECT A.cat_id as cat_id, count(A.cat_id) as cnt, B.category as category FROM books A, bookcatname B WHERE A.cat_id=B.cat_id GROUP BY A.cat_id");

while ($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query) )
{
  echo '<a href="page.php?cat_id='.$category['cat_id'].'">'.$category['category'].' ('.$category['cnt'].')</a><br />';

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

**page.php**

```
<?php 

$dbh=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die ('Cannot connect to the Database' .mysql_errno()); 
mysql_select_db("booksdb");

if ( empty($_GET['cat_id']) )
{
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit();
}



$getCats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE cat_id = '".intval($_GET['cat_id'])."'");

echo '<ul>';

while ( $book = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCats) )
{
   echo '<li>'.$book['title'].'<br />'.$book['author'].'<br />'.'</li><br />';
}

echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486349/dividing-long-list-of-li-tags-into-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using any ul-li, or table, with only css, you can do something like:

```
div
{
column-count:2;
-moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

And you will get something like:

```
<div>
a  b
c  d
e  f
</div>
```

**EDIT**: It seems this css solution is not working in IE (yet).
So best cross-browser approach i know of, would be to use ul-li (setting li width to 50%)

Comment: @JannetMackenzie i am sure its working on most browsers. But just to be on the safe side, check it on IE also. :)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I checked it on IE, it shows in one column only.

Comment: @JannetMackenzie what version of IE?